# update asp.net update panel from code behind after jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a jquery datepicker where when a date is selected, it is passed to the codebehind and in there it is inserted into a dropdownlist. The date is passed fine, but it doesn't get inserted into the dropdownlist. It seems as though the panel doesn't get updated. Is there a way to update panel from codebehind. panel.update(); - doesn't work.
Here is javascript function

```
function clicked() {
$('#<%=link_btn.ClientID%>').click(function() {
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
onSelect: function() {
var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
var newDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy,mm,dd", date);
var dataToSend = { newDate: newDate};
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  data: dataToSend,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(result) {
      alert("success");
 }
 })
}
});
}
```

Comment: You're talking about an ASP.NET UpdatePanel?

Comment: Why not just add the datepicker value to the dropdown with JS? Why send it all the way back to the server?

Comment: yes, asp.net, just edited the question.

Comment: I guess, that's what I would have to do, as I've been searching for a while, and couldn't find why. But I would like to know if there is a way to do it. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Target your dropdown, and append the option, something like `$("#<%=someList.ClientID%>").append("<option>" + newDate + "</option>");`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do to asynchronously update an ASP.NET UpdatePanel from javascript.

## Page javascript

```
var doPostBackAsync = function() { <%= GetBtnClickPostBackReference() %> }
```

## Page markup

```
<asp:LinkButton 
  ID="btnPostBack" 
  runat="server" 
  Visible="true" 
  Style="display: none;" />
```

## Page code

```
protected string GetBtnClickPostBackReference()
{
  return Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnPostBack, "");
}
```

What this does, is allows me to call the javascript function `doPostBackAsync()` and it is like the button inside the [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) was clicked, and causes the [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) to do a `PostBack`. So you would just call `doPostBackAsync` where you currently have your `alert` at.

Comment: Thank you Zack, the function is executed, but panel is not updated, no changes on the client side.